# I/flutter : FormatException: Unexpected end of input (at character 1)

Tags: flutter, post, dart, widget, provider

- I am facing an error when i try to post an OrderRate and comment to the server, i get the below error.

I/flutter (28194): error is: FormatException: Unexpected end of input (at character 1)

- also that is the code which causes the issue:

```
 Future<void> addRateOrder(String comment, int rate, String orderId) async{
     Map<String, dynamic> rateOrderData = Map();
     rateOrderData['Comment'] = comment;
     rateOrderData['Rate'] = rate.toString();
     try{
      String url = Urls.buildRateOrder(orderId);
      final response =  await retry(
         ()=>http.post(url,         
                  body: rateOrderData)
                  .timeout(Duration(seconds: 5)),
                  retryIf: (e)=> e is SocketException || e is TimeoutException
                  );
                  final responseData =json.decode(response.body);
                  print(responseData);

     }catch(error){
       print('error is: $error');
       throw error;
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

sometimes it happens due to sending same request to same Api twice in your code

Comment: Just saying what the problem is most times is no help, you should also suggest a solution to the problem.

Comment: if this was the case , I suggest take all of your data at once in a future builder then use it, if necessary map it and pass it into others via inheritance

Comment: Explain this in your answer and add some code examples so you can help the person asking.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65443986/unexpected-end-of-inputat-character-1?noredirect=1#comment115702287_65443986

you can look at here, and furher look at future builder